# Is a pulse width modulating thermostat compatible with a W2 auxillary heating (Nest compatibility question)

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I have the wiring configuration for a RHEEM thermostat [Pictured Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okmU2.jpg). On it, there is a "V" wiring connection which according to the manufacturer is for "Pulsed width modulation" type heating. On the other end, the furnace, it connects to a "V/W2" connection which I have verified is pulsed width modulating.

Initially, Nest showed that I was incompatible due to the "V" wiring but learned that it was because they thought it was "milivolt" designation. However, after talking with them and researching, I learned that this was not the case and should be able to connect the V/W2 into the Nest "W2".

Will this accomplish the same thing? I learned that W2 is for 2nd stage heating which doesn't seem to be exactly the same thing as Pulsed Width Modulating heating.

[image]

**Edit - Found in manual:**
From [Manual](http://www.globalimageserver.com/fetchdocument-rh.aspx?name=rgjd-installation-instructions)

> To set the furnace for operation with two-stage thermostats, set
>   switches 1 & 2 of SW2 to the “ON” position (See Figure 56). Note that
>   these switches should be in the “OFF” position from the factory. With
>   both switches in the “ON” position, the furnace can still recognize a
>   “V” signal present and will still operate with a modulating
>   thermostat. However, with both switches of SW2 in the “ON” position,
>   the furnace is set to operate with a two-stage thermostat as well.
>   With a two-stage thermostat (installed as shown in Figure 50) and
>   switch settings configured as described above, during a call for heat,
>   the furnace will operate as follows:

So it is currently operating in "modulating" thermostat mode but is able to operate with Nest in a "2-stage" mode by simply flipping a dip switch. Then the "V" wire will act as "W2" wire.

Comment: W2 is typically used for a "second stage" heat or something like emergency heat on a heat pump system.  Unless you can find specific information saying it works with your equipment (PWM or "V wire"), then I  would assume it won't work.

Comment: One reason I think it might is that the furnace has a "V/W2" designation

Comment: PWM is essentially an analog signal instead of just on/off. If a heater could run at a percentage (most can't) instead on/off, PWM would be a way for the thermostat to assume more responsibility in system's control. For example, it could run at 100% when you're away, but only 75% when home, to make it quiet. Or, it could see that "gee, i'm only 1deg cold", so it runs at 50% to catch-up, whereas it ramping up 5deg would use 100%.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. Do you know why they aren't that common. It seems like that would be a useful technology but I don't see a lot of information. Does it not work very well?

Comment: I don't know much about them, but i'm sure they work fine. It's likely a matter of compatibility and momentum. Mercury thermostats are just on/off, and that's basically guaranteed to work, so that's what most digital thermostats do and most furnaces support. It's trivial to run under-floor heat at a percent by switching it on and off several times a second, but it's complicated to do that for gas-based forced air; many solenoid valves are on/off, what do do about the fan speed, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this type of heat is called "modulating heat" or a "modulating furnace".  I can't find any information saying that Nest supports that.

The labels on the thermostat and furnace are meant to be a convenience for the installer, and you really have to refer to the equipment documentation to see what it does. The common labels of R, G, Y, W, C are fairly standard, but once you go beyond that, there are conventions, but you have to research to know the exact use of R, W2, B, etc.

That's a long way of saying that just because the furnace happens to have a W2 label and the Nest also has a W2 label doesn't mean very much.  You have to dig into the documentation (as you have done).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like my furnace can fairly easily be switched to "2 stage mode" and will work with the Nest W2

Comment: @jwillis0720, that's interesting. I did see some discussion about "how efficient" the modulating furnaces were and some people were recommending against disabling that feature.  I haven't used one of these heaters.  Don't accept an answer any time soon - someone else that knows more might have a good answer.

Comment: It doesn't look like that they are that common, so I think maybe they came and went. I just switched it to two stage mode even though I have a modulating thermostat forcing it to operate in 2 stage mode, and will know very soon if I can detect a difference.